# Adding intro slides android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, slide

Here is the intro screen i would like to add into my app[image: Intro Slider]

How do i add it? about 2-3 slides

Comment: use view pager with circular page indicator to set help pages like this

Comment: this person asked a question on 2016-06-14 07:06 and then asnwered itself on 2016-06-14 07:06 with a link to a play store + git hub page. This is an ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this github repo and add the code https://github.com/RxMx/Material-Intro.

The set of intructions are

1. Add the Java, Layouts and the values to your project.
2. To modify the strings of the layouts, change them in the strings.xml
3. Add the WelcomeActivity.java in the manifest and set theme to no Action bar. And it should be set as launcher.

Here is a demo on the playstore https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.todaysfuture.beatboxer

Comment: this person asked a question on 2016-06-14 07:06 and then asnwered itself on 2016-06-14 07:06 with a link to a play store + git hub page. This is an ad

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library also

https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro

if you don't want to use library you can write your own code 
check out following example

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can develop like below is looking exactly what you want
[**Follow Full Demo here.**](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/)

You can customize according to your desired number pages.

[image]